# Why is the projective symmetry group a group?

Tags: symmetry, gauge-invariance, gauge, spin-models

I am reading the paper from X. Wen about quantum orders and symmetric spin liquids. It can be found here: https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0107071

The Hamiltonian he is writing about looks like this:
\begin{align}
H_{MF} = \sum_{<ij>} \Psi_i^\dagger \, U_{ij} \Psi_j + \text{h.c.}  + \text{const.} + \text{Lagrange-multiplier terms}
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
\Psi_i^\dagger :=  (f_{i\uparrow}^\dagger,\,   f_{i\downarrow} )
\end{align}
and $U_{ij}$ is some complex $2\times 2$-matrix. A Gauge-transformation $G$ is a transformation of the form $\Psi_i \to G(i)^\dagger\Psi(i)$, where each $G(i) \in SU(2)$. A symmetry-transformation $T$ is of the form  $\Psi_i \to \Psi_{T^{-1}(i)}$, where (I guess) $T$ has to be a bijective function from the lattice to the lattice.

He introduces something called projective symmetry group (PSG). Its elements are pairs $(G_T,T)$ of a Gauge-transformation together with a symmetry such that the Hamilton operator is invariant under the transformation $G_T T$. This means $(G_T,T) \in PSG$ has to satisfy
\begin{align}
\sum_{<ij>} G_TT(\Psi_i)^\dagger\, U_{ij}\, G_TT(\Psi_j)&= \sum_{<T(i)T(j)>} \Psi_i^\dagger\, G_T(T(i))U_{T(i)T(j)} G_T(T(j))^\dagger\, \Psi_j^\dagger \\&=^! \sum_{<ij>} \Psi_i^\dagger \, U_{ij} \Psi_j
\end{align}
Thus, 
\begin{align}
G(T(i))U_{T(i)T(j)}G(T(j))^\dagger = U_{ij}
\end{align}
I do understand the definition. And I hope I got it right, how Gauge transformation and symmetries act on the basis. But I don't understand why it is calle a group.

So basically I am looking for the group operation
\begin{align}
\cdot: PSG \times PSG \to PSG, \qquad (G_T,T) \cdot (G_S, S) = ?!
\end{align}
It is nowhere mentioned, and I searched a lot. It is probably very easy, but I just can not figure it out. I tried $(G_TG_S,TS)$ and $(G_TG_S, ST)$. Both are of the right form, Gauge and symmetry, but they don't seem to leave the Hamilton invariant. At least I can't see it. I know, that e.g. $G_TTG_SS$ will not change $H_{MF}$, but it is not of the form $(\text{Gauge}, \text{Symmetry})$. So what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother. I think I found the answer. I will write it down here, cause it is hardly found anywhere. Maybe it helps someone in future.

\begin{align}
\cdot : PSG \times PSG \to PSG, \, \qquad (G_T,T)\cdot(G_S,S) := (G_TTG_ST^{-1},TS) 
\end{align}

This has the required form, since 
\begin{align}
G_TTG_ST^{-1} (\Psi_i) = G_T(i)^\dagger G_S(T(i))^\dagger \, \Psi_i
\end{align}
is a Gauge transformation. It is two lines to check associativity. And inverse elements are given by
\begin{align}
(G_T,T)^{-1} = (T^{-1}G_TT,T^{-1})
\end{align}
where the neutral element is $(id,id)$. This also makes $IGG$ a subgroup and $SG = PSG / IGG$ as claimed in the paper. So I am quite happy now. :)

Comment: Do you think the inverse should be $(T^{-1} G^{-1}_T T, T^{-1})$?